# animate method not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation, raphael, jquery-animate

```
function swap(fromTo, toFrom)
{
    var temp = blocks[fromTo];
    var templabel = BlockLabels[fromTo];

    blocks[fromTo].animate({ x: blocks[toFrom].X }, 1500, ">");
    BlockLabels[fromTo].animate({ x: BlockLabels[toFrom].X }, 1500, ">");

    blocks[toFrom].animate({ x: temp.X }, 1500, ">");
    BlockLabels[toFrom].animate({ x: templabel.X }, 1500, ">"); 
}
```

This swap function works in IE9 but not in Chrome. I am using Raphael2.0

updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgEty/
chrome and safari not working but IE9 does

Comment: Do you get any errors at all? Can you please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah...  it's the way you're accessing x as though it were an object property.  Try this instead:

```
blocks[fromTo].animate({ x: blocks[toFrom].attr( 'x' ) }, 1500, ">");
BlockLabels[fromTo].animate({ x: BlockLabels[toFrom].attr( 'x' ) }, 1500, ">");

blocks[toFrom].animate({ x: temp.attr( 'x' ) }, 1500, ">");
BlockLabels[toFrom].animate({ x: templabel.attr( 'x' ) }, 1500, ">");
```

I've [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/95tmh/) as well.

Comment: Just a little Comment, it could be better if you don't write variable names like those. Kind of confussssiiiiiingggg

Comment: toFrom and fromTo, you mean?  Ehh, they make sufficient sense in the context of a swap operation.